# Naming scheme for the two types of line integrals in two-dimensions

Tags: integration

I'm trying to understand the proper naming scheme for the two types of line integrals of a vector field in two dimensions.  Based on my reading, it seems that a vector field line integral in two dimensions is an integral of the form

$$
\mathop{\int}\limits_{C} F \cdot U\  ds 
$$

where F is a vector field, C is an appropriately behaved parametrized curve, ds is the arc length element of C, and U is a unit vector function for which there are apparently only two choices: U can either be T (the unit tangent vector function of C) or n (the normal vector function of C which should point to the right as you traverse the curve C in the forward direction).

In the book I am working through, when U is n then the integral is referred to as a "flux line integral" regardless of whether the curve C is closed or not.  However, when U is T, the line integral is only referred to as a "line integral".  They reserve the name "circulation line integral" to the specific case when the curve C is closed.

This doesn't make sense to me.  Am I missing something?  Shouldn't we refer to a line integral with the T as a "circulation line integral" to be consistent?

As a follow-up, is there any use in choosing other vector functions for U, besides T and n?

Comment: To make things more confusing you can come across line integrals named as [first or second kind](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Curvilinear_integral), or scalar resp. vector line integrals. The latter is imho the best description and the good news is that in dimension two there are only two types of line integrals: scalar $\int_D f\,ds$ and vector $\int_C F_1\,dx+F_2\,dy\,.$ The [usual suspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) describes how to integrate both. BTW: if $(F_1,F_2)$ is tangent or perpendicular to $C$ or none of both depends on $C$ and $F$. No special name needed.